# Req.sessions.user no se guarda luego de moverme de página o cambiar de endpoint | Frontend React y Backend Nodejs

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express, mongoose, express-session

Tengo un backend con nodejs y mongodb en el cual implenté el sessions de express y tengo un login muy simple con passport, lo que pasa es que cuando logra hacer el login guardo en el req.sessions.user la información del usuario y luego de eso respondo al cliente con el usuario para que lo guarde en un context de react para moverlo entre las páginas, la idea es liberarme de esto porque no es nada seguro y por algo tengo un sistema de sesiones, pero no he encontrado ninguna manera de lograr acceder a los req.sessions.user luego de ese login ya que me retornan undefined.
Paso a mostrar los códigos que tengo en el backend y luego lo que tengo hecho en el frontend.

App.js

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import { courseRouter } from "./routes/course.router.js";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import session from 'express-session';
import passport from "passport";
import MongoStore from "connect-mongo"
import config from "./config/dotenv.config.js";
import initializatePassport from "./config/passport.config.js";
import { connectMongo } from "./utils/mongoose.js";
import { loginRouter } from "./routes/login.router.js";

const app = express()

// * Middlewares

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
const port = config.port;
export const mongourl = config.mongourl;

connectMongo();

// * Passport 
app.use(session({
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: mongourl, ttl: 30 * 60}),
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie:{
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 3600000
    }
}));
initializatePassport();
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// ? ruta para nuestra api de usuarios

app.use("/api/cursos", courseRouter);
app.use("/api/users", loginRouter);

app.listen(port || 3001, () => {
    console.log("Server escuchando en el puerto ", port)
})
```

passport.config.js

```
import passport from "passport";
import local from "passport-local";
import { userModel } from "../models/user.model.js";
import { createHash, isValidPassword } from "../utils/bcrypt.js";
import moment from "moment-timezone";


const localStrategy = local.Strategy;
const initializatePassport = () => {
  passport.use("register", new localStrategy(
    {passReqToCallback: true, usernameField: "email"}, async (req, username, password, done) => {
      const {email} = req.body;
      try{
        let user = await userModel.findOne({email: username});
        if(user){
          console.log("User already exist");
          return done(null, false)
        }
        const newUser = {
          email,
          age,
          password: createHash(password)
        }
        let result = await userModel.create(newUser)
        return done(null, result)
      }catch(error){
        return done("Error al obtener el usuario " + error)
      }

      
    }

  ))
  passport.use("login", new localStrategy({usernameField: "email"}, async(username, password, done) => {
    try{
      const user = await userModel.findOne({email: username})
      if(!user){
        return done(null, false)
      }
      if(!isValidPassword(user, password)) return done(null, false);
      const fechaActualArgentina = moment().tz('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
      const fechaHoraArgentina = "login: " + fechaActualArgentina.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
      const res = await userModel.updateOne({email: username}, {last_connection: fechaHoraArgentina})
      return done(null, user)
    } catch(error) {
      return done(error)
    }
  }))
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user._id)
    })

  passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    let user = await userModel.findById(id);
    done(null, user)
  })
}
export default initializatePassport;
```

login.router.js

```
import express from "express";
import passport from 'passport';
import { loginController } from "../controller/login.controller.js"

export const loginRouter = express.Router()

loginRouter.get("/current", loginController.current)

loginRouter.post("/register", passport.authenticate("register", {failureRedirect: "/failRegister"}), loginController.register)

loginRouter.post("/login", passport.authenticate("login", {failureRedirect: "/failLogin"}), loginController.login)
loginRouter.get("/:id", loginController.getLogin);

loginRouter.get("/logout", loginController.logout);
```

login.controller.js

```
import { userModel } from "../models/user.model.js";

class LoginController{
  register(req, res){
    return res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      message: "Register realizado con exito",
      payload: "/"
    })
  }

  async getLogin(req, res){
    const {id } = req.params
    console.log(id);
    const foundUser = await userModel.findById(id);
    console.log(foundUser);
    req.session.user = foundUser
    if(req.session.user){
      
      return res.send({
        loggedIn: true,
        user: req.session.user
      });
    }else {
      return res.send({
        loggedIn: false
      });
    }
  }

  login(req, res) {
    req.session.user = req.user
    return res.status(200).send({
      valid: true,
      user: req.session.user
    });
  }

  logout(req, res){
    req.session.destroy( err => {
      if(!err) res.status(200).json({
        status: "success",
        message: "Deslogueado con exito",
        redirect: "/login"
      })
      else res.send({status: "ERROR", body: err})
    })
  }

  current(req, res){
    return res.send(req.session.user)
  }

}

export const loginController = new LoginController()
```

**Frontend**

Login.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Button} from "reactstrap"
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import "./index.css";
import { usePcContext } from "./Context";

const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const {getUser} = usePcContext();

  const ValorInicial = {
    email: "",
    password: ""
  };

  const [usuario, setUsuario] = useState(ValorInicial);
  
  const checkLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newUser = {
      email: usuario.email,
      password: usuario.password
    };
    const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/users/login", newUser);
    if(response.data.valid){
      console.log(response);
      setUsuario({ ...ValorInicial });
      getUser(response.data.user)
      return navigate("/")
    } else{
      alert("Algo está mal")
    }
  };

  const capturarDatos = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    
    setUsuario({ ...usuario, [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <div className="Crear flexContainer">
      <div className="col-md-10 listas offset-md-3 align-center formCard">
        <div className="card card-body">
          <h1 className="">Login</h1>
          <Form onSubmit={checkLogin}>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label
                for="exampleEmail"
                hidden
              >
                Email
              </Label>
              <Input
                id="exampleEmail"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Email"
                type="email"
                value={usuario.email}
                onChange={capturarDatos}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            {' '}
            <FormGroup>
              <Label
                for="examplePassword"
                hidden
              >
                Password
              </Label>
              <Input
                id="examplePassword"
                name="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                type="password"
                value={usuario.password}
                onChange={capturarDatos}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            {' '}
            <Button>
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login;
```

ListaUsuario.js (seria donde traigo unas tarjetas pero tambien necesito el req.sessions para mostrar quien está logueado)

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Contador from "./Contador";
import { usePcContext } from "./Context";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import moment from "moment-timezone";
import User from "./User";

const ListaUsuario = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [lista, setLista] = useState([]);
  const { findIdStock, stock, updateStock, user } = usePcContext();
  const [codigosVisible, setCodigosVisible] = useState({});
  const [editingCourse, setEditingCourse] = useState(null);
  const [entregasRealizadas, setEntregasRealizadas] = useState([]); // Array de cursos entregados
  const [coursesWithExpiredDelivery, setCoursesWithExpiredDelivery] = useState([]);
  const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false);

  const editarCurso = (cursoId) => {
    setEditingCourse(cursoId);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      if(user._id === undefined){
        console.log("No está logueado");
        return navigate("/login");
      } 
      const getUser = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/users/" + user._id)
      if(!getUser.data.loggedIn){
        console.log("No está logueado");
        return navigate("/login");
      }
      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/cursos");
      const cursosData = res.data.payload.cursos.map((curso) => {
        const horaRetiradaArgentina = moment(curso.horaRetirada).tz("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        const updatedAtArgentina = moment(curso.updatedAt).tz("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        const horaEntregaAtArgentina = moment(curso.horaEntrega).tz("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        return { ...curso, horaRetirada: horaRetiradaArgentina, updatedAt: updatedAtArgentina, horaEntrega: horaEntregaAtArgentina };
      });
      setLista(cursosData);

      if (stock === 120) {
        const stockRetirado = cursosData.reduce((total, curso) => total + curso.cantidad, 0);
        updateStock(stock - stockRetirado);
      }

      const timer = setInterval(() => {
        const cursosConEntregaVencida = cursosData.filter((curso) => moment(curso.horaEntrega).isBefore(moment()));
        if (cursosConEntregaVencida.length > 0) {
          setCoursesWithExpiredDelivery(cursosConEntregaVencida);
          setShowAlert(true);
        } else {
          setCoursesWithExpiredDelivery([]);
          setShowAlert(false);
        }
      }, 1000);

      return () => clearInterval(timer);
    };
      fetchData();
  }, [stock]);

  const eliminarCurso = async (id) => {
    await axios.delete("http://localhost:3001/api/cursos/" + id);
    findIdStock(lista, id);

    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/cursos");
    const cursosData = res.data.map((curso) => {
      // Formatea la hora de retirada a la zona horaria de Argentina (Buenos Aires)
      const horaRetiradaArgentina = moment(curso.horaRetirada).tz("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
      // Formatea la hora de actualización (updatedAt) a la zona horaria de Argentina (Buenos Aires)
      const updatedAtArgentina = moment(curso.updatedAt).tz("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
      const horaEntregaAtArgentina = moment(curso.horaEntrega).tz("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
      return { ...curso, horaRetirada: horaRetiradaArgentina, updatedAt: updatedAtArgentina, horaEntrega: horaEntregaAtArgentina };
    });
    setLista(cursosData);

    setCoursesWithExpiredDelivery((prevCourses) => prevCourses.filter((curso) => curso._id !== id));
    setShowAlert(false); // Ocultar la alerta después de entregar un curso

    // Reiniciar la página
    window.location.reload();
  };

  const toggleCodigosVisible = (cursoId) => {
    setCodigosVisible((prevVisible) => ({
      ...prevVisible,
      [cursoId]: !prevVisible[cursoId],
    }));
  };

  const onAdd = (qty) => {
    alert(`Entregaste ${qty} computadoras`);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-10">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-10 mb-2 mt-4">
              {showAlert && coursesWithExpiredDelivery.length > 0 && (
                <div className="alert alert-danger">
                  <p>¡La hora de entrega ha pasado para los siguientes cursos:</p>
                  <ul>
                    {coursesWithExpiredDelivery.map((curso) => (
                      <li key={curso._id}>
                        {curso.nombre} (curso: {curso.profesor})
                      </li>
                    ))}
                  </ul>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
            {lista.map((cursos) => (
              <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-6 p-2" key={cursos._id}>
                <div className="card shadow">
                  <div className="card-header">
                    <div>
                      <h5>Registra: {cursos.nombre}</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="card-body">
                    <p>Curso: {cursos.profesor}</p>
                    <p>Cantidad: {cursos.cantidad}</p>
                    <p>
                      Artículos:
                      {cursos.tipoArticulo.map((tipo, index) => (
                        <span key={index}>
                          {index > 0 && ", "} {/* Separador de comas entre tipos */}
                          {tipo}
                        </span>
                      ))}
                    </p>
                    <p>Fecha y hora de retirada: {cursos.horaRetirada}</p>
                    <p>Fecha y hora de actualización: {cursos.updatedAt}</p>
                    <p>Fecha y hora de entrega: {cursos.horaEntrega}</p>
                  </div>

                  <div className="card-footer">
                    <div className="mb-2">
                      <button
                        className="btn btn-success form-control"
                        onClick={() => eliminarCurso(cursos._id)}
                        disabled={entregasRealizadas.includes(cursos._id)}
                      >
                        Entregar
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="mb-2">
                      <Link to={`/editpage/${cursos._id}`}>
                        <button className="btn btn-primary form-control">
                          Editar
                        </button>
                      </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="mb-2">
                      <button
                        className="btn btn-secondary form-control"
                        onClick={() => toggleCodigosVisible(cursos._id)}
                      >
                        {codigosVisible[cursos._id] ? 'Ocultar Códigos' : 'Mostrar Códigos'}
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    {codigosVisible[cursos._id] && (
                      <div>
                        <p>Códigos de computadora:</p>
                        <p>{cursos.codigo}</p>
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-12 col-md-2">
          <Contador onAdd={onAdd} initial={1} />
          <User user={user}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ListaUsuario;
```

No sé si necesitan que les muestre algo más.
¿Alguno tiene idea de que tengo que hacer?